# Loading Data Set with Breaks

Tags: python, csv, line-breaks

I'm trying to load a dataset with breaks in it. I am trying to find an intelligent way to make this work. I got started on it with the code i included.

As you can see, the data within the file posted on the public FTP site starts at line 11, ends at line 23818, then starts at again at 23823, and ends at 45,630.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from io import BytesIO
    from zipfile import ZipFile
    from urllib.request import urlopen

    url = urlopen("http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/10_Portfolios_Prior_12_2_Daily_CSV.zip")
    #Download Zipfile and create pandas DataFrame
    zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(url.read()))
    df = pd.read_csv(zipfile.open('10_Portfolios_Prior_12_2_Daily.CSV'), header = 0, 
                        names = ['asof_dt','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'], skiprows=10).dropna()
    df['asof_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['asof_dt'], format = "%Y%m%d")
```

I would ideally like the first set to have a version number "1", the second to have "2", etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any breaks in this data other than the initial few at the beginning

Comment: Please go to row 22823

Comment: No break in the data at the URL. Reads straight into pandas without complaint after the first few lines are tossed.

Comment: Try something like `awk 'FNR>=22803 && FNR<=22843' 10_Portfolios_Prior_12_2_Daily.CSV`  No break in sight. Just skip the beginning and you're good

Comment: My apologies, I put in the wrong row number. There's a break between 23818 and 23822. I cannot hard code a row break number because they append the data in each section on a periodic basis. Thank you

Comment: Simplest thing is to just clean up your data before it gets into pandas - just skip any lines that don't start with the relevantly-sized integer. You are already reading the whole thing into memory anyway.

Comment: I don't control the format of the input. Are you suggesting that I set up a process between downloading the zip file and reading it into python?

Comment: What do you mean by process? You've read the whole thing into memory right? `readlines` it right up and clean up the stuff you don't want. then put into pandas. Should be an extra couple of lines.

Comment: I would have to manually change the numbers for FNR and FNR each time, correct?

Comment: No no. I'm talking about doing it in python as you are now. Just filter the bad lines out. No hardcoding of line numbers, just pick a reasonable criterion like, 'if line everything up to first comma is not digits' toss it.